# LightDM accepts password once, and never again

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, xorg

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.  Fresh install, although I'm pretty sure I'm going to need to reinstall after this problem is resolved.

When I first start Ubuntu, I get the LightDM login screen.  That screen accepts my password and signs me in to my desktop.  However, if I lock the screen during that session, and come back, LightDM (or XOrg?) will not accept my password.  The only solution is to reboot.  I can drop to console with CTRL+ALT+F1, and sign in there with no trouble.  I can "passwd" myself a new password, however I still cannot sign in when I go back to the window manager with CTRL+ALT+F7.  If I reboot, I can use the new password I made for myself.

I've tried reinstalling XOrg and LightDM with apt-get install --reinstall, however neither have solved the problem.

Comment: It seems that the LOCK screen is the trouble here.  If I lock my screen, my password is denied.  However, if I click my name in the top right, go to Switch User, I'm brought back to the original log on screen.  Typing my password here will unlock the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a password which consists only from numbers? I think there is a problem think keyboard layout.

Comment: Doesn't help.  Added comment to question to update new information in the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After some investigation, I noticed that I had several different screen savers active in the session configuration. Although I had a fresh Xubuntu 14.04 system installation, there might have been some older configs in my user's home directory (which I copied from the old installation).

In Xubuntu/xfce4 the extra screen savers can be disabled in the Settings -> Sessions and Startup -> Application Autostart menu.